# How to do a Interactive HTML Startup

Tags: html, css, interactive

I am currently just working on a couple little projects with a personal Website I have. When researching i found a little interatice gimmick i really liked, but could not find anywhere.
On https://piratebay.com/ it asks you too hold the Spacebar which then lets a graphically animated rocket start and then sends you to the main index. Does anyone know where to find templates like this?
Any help is appreciated.
Alex

Comment: The scope of this question is too broad to give specific answers. The OP is looking for examples of interactive animations is web pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can type in search box what you looking for such as profile or menus or buttons or etc..

1. http://codepen.io/
2. http://cssdeck.com/
3. http://cssdeck.com/
4. http://plnkr.co/
5. https://tympanus.net/codrops/
6. https://codemyui.com/
7. https://codyhouse.co/library/